# Notation $\mathrm{mod} $ in ergodic theory

Tags: measure-theory, notation, ergodic-theory

Does someone know, what exactly is meant by the following:

$$T^{-1}A=A \mod \mu$$

where $\mu$ is a $T$-invariant measure?

Comment: Presumably it means that the equality modulo a set of measure zero for $\mu$. (Cf. an equality holding $\mu$-a.e.)

Comment: Thanks, so I might as well could write $T^{-1}A=A \text{ } \mu \text{ -a.e.}$..?

Comment: Well, it doesn't really make sense to say that it holds $\mu$-a.e.; that's usually to describe a property $P(x)$ that holds for $x\in E$ off a set of measure zero.

Comment: $B=A \mod \mu$ $\iff$ $\mu(B \Delta A)=0$ $\iff$ ${\boldsymbol 1}_B={\boldsymbol 1}_A \quad \mu \text{ a.e.}$.